# Ajax.BeginForm with Collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Isn't that possible to use "Ajax.BeginForm" in a collection model? Form repeats itself, Html elements are rendered correctly, values are ok. However, all parameters going through action are being null.

I've realized that, it posts like that:

```
ProductList[0].Id   501
ProductList[0].quantity 1
```

However it should be like

```
Id  501
quantity    1
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: show your view code + the model being rendered

Answer (score 0):

You should use prefix in UpdateModel function:

```
UpdateModel(MyModel, "MyModel")
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using pure html, thanks anyway.

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" name="Id"/>
<input type="text" value="" name="quantity"/>
```